# Error menuitem odoo

Tags: menuitem, odoo-8

i add my menuitem to my module , but i get error i dont know how to solve it
this my code xml :

```
     <record id="action_sequences" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Gestion des Sequences</field>
        <field name="res_model">ir.sequence</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('code','in',['FE','RF' 'OI', 'OP', 'OR', 'OD'])]</field>
    </record>


    <menuitem id="menu_sequences" parent="menu_configuration" name="Sequences" action="action_sequences" sequence="60" />
```

the error that i get is :

Odoo Erreur (côté interface)

Error: Expected "]", got "(string)"

http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a coma `,` after `'RF'`. Try below code:

```
<field name="domain">[('code','in',['FE','RF', 'OI', 'OP', 'OR', 'OD'])]</field>
```